# Is there any way to use echo and not print a new line in Nim

Tags: echo, nim-lang

My code:

```
echo "Name: "
var input = readLine(stdin)

echo "Your name is: " + input
```

What I get:

```
Name:
<your name>
Your name is: <your name>
```

What I want to get (notice how there's no newline after "Name: "):

```
Name: <your name>
Your name is: <your name>
```

I want to know if there's a way to do that in Nim using `echo`. I know that I can use `stdout.write`, but is there a way to do that with just `echo`? Thanks to anyone who can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you said it yourself, you should use `stdout.write`.

`echo` is not a keyword, but just a built-in proc, so you can easily check its definition: [echo in the system module](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#echo%2Cvarargs%5Btyped%2C%5D). And, as you can see, the only arguments it takes are the things to print out.

So yeah, if you want to not have a newline, use `stdout.write`. If you want to automatically stringify all arguments, you can just create a wrapper proc in the same way `echo` works:

```
proc myecho(x: varargs[string, `$`]) = 
  for arg in x:
    stdout.write arg
  stdout.flushFile()

myecho "Name: "
var input = readLine(stdin)
myecho "Your name is: ", input
```

Also, if you want to specifically not print a newline for prompts (like asking the user for input), you might want to give the [rdstdin](https://nim-lang.org/docs/rdstdin.html) module a try instead:

```
import std/rdstdin

let name = readLineFromStdin("Name: ")
echo "Your name is: ", name
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, that really helped. I am really noob at Nim but experienced in Python, any tips to learning Nim faster?